# Where to begin for writing a video streaming application in C#?

Tags: c#, video, network-programming, streaming, mp4

I want to make an application where I could contact the server (computer hosting a mp4 video file) and then it would stream and play the video. The streaming and video playing would take place in the same application.

I have no idea where to begin. What technologies would I need to know to start implementing this? Any sort of direction would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/) blog article which seems like it's what you're looking for. In his example, he streams the video from his local computer but streaming from a server should be along the same lines.